# Parenthesis for not pure functions

Tags: scala, coding-style

I know that that I should use () by convention if a method has side effects

```
def method1(a: String): Unit = {
  //.....
}

//or

def method2(): Unit = {
  //.....
}
```

Do I have to do the same thing if a method doesn't have side effects but it's not pure, doesn't have any parameters and, of course, it returns the different results each time it's being called?

```
def method3() = getRemoteSessionId("login", "password")
```

Comment: I don't know the exact definition of "side effect", but how can a non-pure function produce its result without side effects? If a function uses a random number generator or reads from any I/O, I would consider this a side effect.

Comment: *In computer science, a function or expression is said to have a side effect if, in addition to returning a value, it also modifies some state **or has an observable interaction with calling functions of the outside world.*** [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science))

Comment: @om-nom-nom, why don't think that functions of the outside world can be pure?

Comment: I've always understood the parens to indicate side-effects, so my answer would be "no". By analogy, we don't have parens or any way of distinguishing identifiers for vars, as opposed to vals, and impure vs pure functions is basically the same difference (impure functions being like mutable values).

Comment: @Alex well, I'm personally and most of the people I worked with used to treat *outside world* (e.g. different kinds of IO) as something less predictable and in general case impure (may return different results from different runs). So I would say you would be better to put braces to indicate this fact. But again, this is personal opinion.

Comment: @om-nom-nom Calling a random generator with global state will (hopefully) modify that state, making it possible to indirectly observe the interaction by seeing that something changed. The same thing could apply to reading from a file ("last accessed" date may change, the program may apply a read lock on the file, and so on.) I would hold that in all cases (barring some weird edge case I can't think of right now), impurity implies having side-effects. (Or rather, having the potential to cause side effects – which is the real worry with impure functions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** After reviewing Luigi Plinge's comment, I came to think that I should rewrite the answer. This is also not a clear yes/no answer, but some suggestions.

---

First: The case regarding `var` is an interesting one. Declaring a `var foo` gives you a getter `foo` *without* parentheses. Obviously it is an impure call, but it does not have a side effect (it does not change anything unobserved by the caller).

Second, regarding your question: I now would not argue that the problem with `getRemoteSessionId` is that it is impure, but that it actually makes the server maintain some session login for you, so clearly you interfere destructively with the environment. Then `method3()` should be written with parentheses because of this side-effect nature.

A third example: Getting the contents of a directory should thus be written `file.children` and not `file.children()`, because again it is an impure function but should not have side effects (other than perhaps a read-only access to your file system).

A fourth example: Given the above, you should write `System.currentTimeMillis`. I *do tend* to write `System.currentTimeMillis()` however...

Using this forth case, my tentative answer would be: **Parentheses are preferable when the function has either a side-effect; or if it is impure and depending on state not under the control of your program.**

With this definition, it would not matter whether `getRemoteSessionId` has known side-effects or not. On the other hand, it implies to revert to writing `file.children()`...

Comment: re: 2nd paragraph: doesn't "having side-effects" refer only to side-effects caused by the function itself? For example, any kind of mutable variable getter is impure but should *not* have side-effects, so I'd disagree with "not being pure is synonymous with having side effects".

Comment: @LuigiPlinge I have rewritten the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The [Scala style guide](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html#parentheses) recommends:

> Methods which act as accessors of any sort (either encapsulating a field or a logical property) should be declared without parentheses except if they have side effects.

It doesn't mention any other use case besides accessors. So the question boils down to whether you regard this method as an accessor, which in turns depends on how the rest of the class is set up and perhaps also on the (intended) call sites.

Comment: `def method3() = getRemoteSessionId("login", "password")` can't be an accessor.

Comment: @Alex: then I'd put in parentheses.